# Dagger2 dependency - Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm trying to add Dagger2 to my project in Android Studio but I can't find proper dependency to paste in build.gradle. Could you help and send me the proper line?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

### [Installing Dagger 2 on Android Studio 2](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration)

```
// Application build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4"
}
```

**Maven Repositories:**

Find the latest versions of the above dependencies in the Maven Repository:

- [dagger](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger)
- [dagger-compiler](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger-compiler)

---

### Notes: Android Studio < 2.2

Older versions of Android Studio need `android-apt` for annotation processing.

```
// Project build.gradle
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Assists in working with annotation processors for Android Studio.
        // No longer needed with Android Studio 2.2+
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

And

```
// Application build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4"
}
```

---

### Notes: Dagger < 2.1

For Dagger < 2.1-SNAPSHOT the `javax.annotation` is needed for the `@Generated` annotation used in Dagger generated code (see [github.com/google/dagger/issues/95](http://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95)). The annotation is not included in the Android API jar, so you'll need to use one of these libraries ([see differences](http://codeblast.com/2015/08/06/dagger2-jsr250-annotations/)):

```
// Application build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

- [javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/jsr250-api)
- [javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api)
- [org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.annotation)

Comment: compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' is what did it for me, otherwise i kept getting NPE from gradle.  Why did the devs not mention this dependency?  Thanks again!

Comment: Do I need javax.annotations if I use java 7?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko You'll need it for all Android projects, since android uses Java 6. See https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95

Comment: You dont need the apt plugin anymore , please check my updated answer below

Comment: Android Studio says to change to implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4' instead of compile

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need the android-apt plugin anymore**,all functionality that was previously provided by android-apt is now available in the Android **Gradle plugin version 2.2**

https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

Update Gradle plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

and Dagger dependencies to

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

in your app/build.gradle

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
}
```

in build.gradle of your project.

Comment: The current latest build available is 2.1-SNAPSHOT  ( so you can use `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.1-SNAPSHOT' `)

Comment: Dagger 2.0 is now out in Maven Central proper. Don't use snapshots unless you're prepared to deal with breakage.

Answer (score 5):

I had some trouble with this earlier today.  Here's what worked for me with the latest versions as of this date using Android Studio 2.0 preview 8:

buid.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.redacted.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

}
```

build.gradle (Project:proj):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha8'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these latest dependencies in your app/build.gradle with the latest version of Android studios 3.0

```
dependencies {

//Dagger
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'

}
```

Simple implementation of Dagger 2 [Dagger 2 with MVP](https://github.com/rkandoroidrepo/android-dagger2-example)

Answer (score 0):

***Updating latest version of Dagger-2 dependencies***

Current version: 2.36. You can find the latest versions of all the below dependencies [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.dagger).

For core dagger dependencies,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.36'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.36'
}
```

For android dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.36'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.36'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.36'
```

If your project is using [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), then use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`. To use `kapt`, you need to add the [plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-gradle) `kotlin-kapt` in your Gradle.

Comment: actually Im a Naive in android .So , can you please tell what the diff.  betn 'Android Dependencies' and 'dependencies'