# DaggerComponents not getting generated in android

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

- I am Using
  [***https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2***](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2)
  ... and followed all steps
- I am Able to sync the application and see the Dagger Dependencies

***Issue I am facing***:

```
//DaggerNetComponent is not getting generated
mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) 
                .netModule(new NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
                .build();
```

### NET MODULE

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


@Module
public class NetModule {
    String mBaseUrl;

    public NetModule(String mBaseUrl) {
        this.mBaseUrl = mBaseUrl;
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.cache(cache);
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

### APP MODULE

```
import android.app.Application;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;


@Module
public class AppModule {

    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application mApplication) {
        this.mApplication = mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

### NET COMPONENT

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;
import retrofit.modules.AppModule;
import retrofit.modules.NetModule;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

How to Debug this so I am able to generate this class

Comment: Could you paste here NetComponent code along with AppModule and NetModule?

Comment: @AlexanderBilchuk ... I have added the Code

Comment: did you try to rebuild your project? and notice any build errors?

Comment: There are no build errors ... I rebuilt the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of `Cache provideHttpCache(Application application)` in `NetModule`.

Yes, you provides `Application` within `AppModule`, but it does not have any association with `NetComponent`.

So, there are three ways:

**1**. Just pass `Application` manually into `NetComponent` the same way you did it with `AppComponent` (via constructor)

or (better way)

**2**. Create separate `Component` for `AppModule` - `AppComponent` which should provide `Application` to other components:

```
@Component(modules = {
   AppModule.class,
})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
   Application application();
}
```

And then make your `NetComponent` to be dependent from `AppComponent`:

```
@Component(
   dependencies = AppComponent.class,
   modules = NetModule.class
)
@NetScope
public interface NetComponent {
   void inject(AddTranslationActivity activity);
}
```

or

**3**. Do the same as described in item **2**, but using [Dagger subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger//subcomponents.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting build errors and the Dagger component class does not exist, it sounds like the Dagger annotation processor is not running.

You'll need to [add the annotation processors to your gradle dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768141/1290264). For example:

```
// Application build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try invalidating caches:

```
File>>Invalidate Caches\Restart>>Invalidate and Restart
```